# How to use a smartphone / tablet battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have a c11-me172v battery from Asus tablet. I tried but didn't manage to find a datasheet. There are 6 wires - two red, two black, yellow and white:

[image]

How it should be connected to power my circuit? How to charge it in DIY devices? Does it have a build-in interface that allows to figure out current charge or it's done somehow else, using external components?

Comment: I'm guessing it's two power leads on the outside (red & black) and perhaps an I2C bus in the middle with dedicated power control circuitry inside.  That's what was inside my HP laptop battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical Li-Po battery singe cell. Two Black wires are ground, two Red wires are positive terminal.

Green wire is related to battery temperature sensor, and the next White wire is battery ID (some serial format).

For DIY purposes you can simply charge the cell as usual for Li-Ion cells and ignore ID and temperature sensor wires. From my experience with this line of ASUS products, the safe charging current for this cell would be ~2A, and the terminal voltage 4.2V for full charging capacity. Or even higher. At least my MemoPad ME851 has similar battery with no-load voltage that reads at 4.293V fully charged.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. If you want a battery to use in your projects, use one that comes with a datasheet.

Lithium-ion batteries are, like wizards, subtle and swift to anger. Using one without any knowledge of its capacity and limitations is foolish -- you have no way to know what the battery's charge and current capacity are, nor do you have any way to know how to recharge it safely.

Comment: This battery comes from a consumer device from a very reputable manufacturer, and therefore it is very safe to assume that it is fully protected (internally). If one is overly concerned with "safety", the cell can be charged with sub-optimal current, say 1A or 500mA. This will never give any harm. Again, this is for DYI project, not for some space-grade or medical certified equipment. And urban legends about "swift and anger" cells are a matter of the past or intentional abuse.